# Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--evalsha'

Tags: redis, lua, redis-cli

When I run `redis-cli script load "$(cat ./scripts/restoreSymbols.lua)"` for the following script:

```
local list = {}
local result = redis.call('scan', 0, 'MATCH', 'symbol:*', 'COUNT', 1000)
for _, v in ipairs(result[2]) do
    list[#list+1] = redis.call('hgetall', v)
end
return list
```

I get a sha `a8a6b471abf42b6cc584444e9d269e9807d96ff1` but when I then run `redis-cli --evalsha a8a6b471abf42b6cc584444e9d269e9807d96ff1` I get:

```
Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--evalsha'
```

How is this possible? I don't need any options or arguments. The script is working (debugged it with the debugger) and also runs when I normal --eval it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--evalsha` flag is not a valid `redis-cli` option. You can use `--eval` to run your script like

```sh
redis-cli --eval ./scripts/restoreSymbols.lua
```

But if you want to use `evalsha` to run a loaded script, what you need to do is

```sh
redis-cli evalsha a8a6b471abf42b6cc584444e9d269e9807d96ff1 0
```

Note that you have to pass the `0` to indicate that you are not passing any argument to the command.

Comment: So simple. Sorry for asking :)

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about :) It was a legitimate question.